# Keeping proof of requests from coworkers

Tags: colleagues, email, training

If a colleague asks me for something (for example to show them how to use something), is it ok for me to ask them to send me an e-mail with their request, and then for me to answer them also in written form in the e-mail?

I would like to do this to keep a trail of what happens, what requests I get, and to be able to prove what I spend the time on. In addition, some coworkers will sometimes want to mock me in front of someone else for mis-teaching them, and I'm wondering if this email papertrail will help in disproving them in case they attempt to discredit me.

I wanted to ask what some good practices for these are? And if this is acceptable, to ask a colleague (even a new colleague) whenever he has a question to write down the question or the request in written form on email.

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by your coworkers mocking you? Also, is there anyone in your office specifically responsible for training?

Comment: @Pyrotechnical For that particular incident, yes, there was a person in the office that was specifically designated to be a trainer. But this coworker asked me in the daily morning standup meeting with help regarding a topic. Then after I helped him, he called the trainer to "fact-check" with them, and then mocked me to the trainer and twisted my words, with me sitting across the desk from his. How would you tackle this kind of behavior?  Thanks

Answer (score 6):

> ask them to send me an e-mail with their request, and then for me to answer them also in written form in the e-mail?

Not only is this okay, but this is also a good practice to keep track of the requests that were made to you.
When somebody oraly makes a request to you, you can ask something like

> Oh okay I will do X. Can you send me an email detailing what YZ you expect me to do in this X task so that I don't forget anything you just said to me?

If the person is reluctent, **YOU send that person an email** saying :

> Hi Bob, As discussed with you I will do X with the following tasks A, B
>   & C.

That way no answer from that person will imply acknowledgment.